# Editar y eliminar registros de mysql desde datatable

Tags: php, mysql, datatable

He adaptado un ejemplo de datatable con un datepicker.
Ahora quiero añadirle las funciones de editar y eliminar registros. Tengo otro ejemplo que con el que puedo editar y eliminar filas de la base de datos, pero no soy capaz de adaptarlo para hacerlo funcionar en la datatable con datepicker.

Me ha sido muy fácil adaptar los dos ejemplos por separado, pero después de varias horas me veo incapaz de hacerlos funcionar de forma conjunta.

Cuando pulso en el link "editar" me lleva a edit.php tomando el número de ID de la fila, pero no me carga los valores que tiene asignados "cliente" y "proveedor"

Cuando pulso  el link "eliminar" me lleva a la url delete.php tomando el numero de ID y se queda en ella sin borrarlo.
En el ejemplo base cuando pulso el link "eliminar" borrar el registro automáticamente y vuelve a la pagina "index.php"

Os dejo link a la demo:
http://www.buendialogistica.com/index.html/datatable/ejemplo3/index.php

Aquí muestro la tabla con todos los registros, con los filtros por fecha y un filtro que busca en todas las celdas.
index.php

```
<html>
     <head>
      <title>Filtrar datos por fechas usando datatables con PHP y MySQL</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/csscustom.css">  
      <link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <style>
       body
       {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color:#f1f1f1;
       }
       .box
       {
        width:1270px;
        padding:20px;
        background-color:#fff;
        border:2px solid #ccc;
        border-radius:5px;
        margin-top:25px;
       }
      </style>


     </head>
     <body>

      <div class="container box">



       <h1 align="center"> Filtrar datos por fechas usando datatables con PHP y MySQL</h1>
       <br />






       <div class="table-responsive"  style="overflow-x: hidden;">
        <br />
        <div class="row">
         <div class="input-daterange">
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" class="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" class="form-control" />
          </div>      
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info active" />
         </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table id="order_data" class="table  table-striped  table-hover">
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th>Orden ID</th>
           <th>Documento</th>
           <th>Cliente</th>
           <th>Producto</th>
           <th>Precio</th>
           <th>Iva</th>
           <th>Estado</th>
           <th>Fecha</th>
           <th>Editar</th>
           <th>Eliminar</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
        </table>

       </div>
      </div>
      <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

     </body>
    </html>



    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >



    $(document).ready(function(){




     $('.input-daterange').datepicker({
        "locale": {
                    "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Aplicar",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancelar",
            "fromLabel": "Desde",
            "toLabel": "Hasta",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Do",
                "Lu",
                "Ma",
                "Mi",
                "Ju",
                "Vi",
                "Sa"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "Enero",
                "Febrero",
                "Marzo",
                "Abril",
                "Mayo",
                "Junio",
                "Julio",
                "Agosto",
                "Septiembre",
                "Octubre",
                "Noviembre",
                "Diciembre"
            ],
            "firstDay": 1
        },

      format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
      autoclose: true

     });

     fetch_data('no');

     function fetch_data(is_date_search, start_date='', end_date='')
     {
      var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({

        "language":{
           "lengthMenu":"Mostrar _MENU_ registros por página.",
           "zeroRecords": "Lo sentimos. No se encontraron registros.",
                 "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                 "infoEmpty": "No hay registros aún.",
                 "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                 "search" : "Búsqueda",
                 "LoadingRecords": "Cargando ...",
                 "Processing": "Procesando...",
                 "SearchPlaceholder": "Comience a teclear...",
                 "paginate": {
         "previous": "Anterior",
         "next": "Siguiente", 
         }
          },

       "processing" : true,
       "serverSide" : true,
       "sort": false,
       "order" : [],
       "ajax" : {
        url:"ajax.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{
         is_date_search:is_date_search, start_date:start_date, end_date:end_date
        }
       }
      });
     }

     $('#search').click(function(){
      var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
      var end_date = $('#end_date').val();
      if(start_date != '' && end_date !='')
      {
       $('#order_data').DataTable().destroy();
       fetch_data('yes', start_date, end_date);
      }
      else
      {
       alert("Por favor seleccione la fecha");
      }
     }); 

    });
    </script>
```

Con este archivo hago la consulta a la base de datos. 
En el ejemplo inicial no tenia las columnas de editar y eliminar, se las he añadido a "posteriori".

ajax.php

```
<?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "databasename");//Configurar los datos de conexion
        $columns = array('idviaje','cliente', 'proveedor', 'nombre_carga1', 'nombre_carga2', 'referencia_cliente','referencia_carga1', 'fecha_carga');

        $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes WHERE ";

        if($_POST["is_date_search"] == "yes")
        {
         $query .= 'fecha_carga BETWEEN "'.$_POST["start_date"].'" AND "'.$_POST["end_date"].'" AND ';
        }

        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
        {
         $query .= '
          (idviaje LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
          OR proveedor LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
          OR nombre_carga1 LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
          OR cliente LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
          OR nombre_carga2 LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%")
         ';
        }


        if(isset($_POST["order"]))
        {
         $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
         ';
        }
        else
        {
         $query .= 'ORDER BY idviaje DESC ';
        }

        $query1 = '';

        if($_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
         $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
        }

        $number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

        $data = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $idviaje=$row["idviaje"];
         $fecha_carga=date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row["fecha_carga"]));            
         $sub_array = array();
         $sub_array[] = $row["idviaje"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["cliente"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["proveedor"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["nombre_carga1"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["nombre_carga2"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["referencia_cliente"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["referencia_carga1"];
         $sub_array[] = $fecha_carga;
         $sub_array[] = '<a href="edit.php?id='.$idviaje.'" class="btn btn-xs default">Editar</a>';
         $sub_array[] = '<a href="delete.php?id='.$idviaje.'" ">Eliminar</a>';


         $data[] = $sub_array;
        }

        function get_all_data($connect)
        {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM viajes";
         $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
         return mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }

        $output = array(
         "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
         "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
         "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
         "data"    => $data
        );

        echo json_encode($output);

        ?>
```

Con ester archivo elimino registros de la base de datos con su ID.

delete.php

```
<?php
    /*
    Author: Javed Ur Rehman
    Website: https://www.allphptricks.com/
    */

    require('db.php');
    $id=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM viajes WHERE idviaje=$id"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die ( mysqli_error());
    header("Location: index.php"); 
    ?>
```

Con este archivo cargo los datos con el indentificador ID y los actualizo.

edit.php

```
<?php
    /*
    Author: Javed Ur Rehman
    Website: https://www.allphptricks.com/
    */

    require('db.php');

    $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
    $query = "SELECT * from viajes where idviaje='".$idviaje."'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Update Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form">
    <p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a> | <a href="insert.php">Insert New Record</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
    <h1>Update Record</h1>
    <?php
    $status = "";
    if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
    {
    $idviaje=$_REQUEST['idviaje'];
    $name =$_REQUEST['cliente'];
    $age =$_REQUEST['proveedor'];
    $update="update viajes set cliente='".$name."', proveedor='".$age."' where idviaje='".$idviaje."'";
    mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
    $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
    echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
    }else {
    ?>
    <div>
    <form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
    <input name="idviaje" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['idviaje'];?>" />
    <p><input type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Enter Name" required value="<?php echo $row['cliente'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="proveedor" placeholder="Enter Age" required value="<?php echo $row['proveedor'];?>" /></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>

    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="https://www.allphptricks.com/insert-view-edit-and-delete-record-from-database-using-php-and-mysqli/">Tutorial Link</a> <br /><br />
    For More Web Development Tutorials Visit: <a href="https://www.allphptricks.com/">AllPHPTricks.com</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien el planteamiento de tu pregunta. No obstante, mediante el uso de Ajax es sumamente fácil hacer que tu código trabaje de forma conjunta. Sería cuestión de asignar ids diferentes para cada acción: `Editar, Eliminar, Insertar...` o lo que quieras, escuchar los `clicks` de cada elemento y lanzar una llamada distinta al servidor según la acción seleccionada. Incluso eso se puede hacer en background, sin necesidad de redirecciones o recargas de páginas.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo A.Cedano. Soy muy novato en programación y no entiendo completamente la lógica de los códigos que estoy utilizando. Como digo por separado me funcionan pero juntos no.

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente Xavier. Lo que quiero decir es que con Ajax se te abren posibilidades muy interesantes. Por ejemplo, podrías tener varios botones en una misma página y lanzar actividades distintas según el botón presionado, ejecutar acciones en el servidor, cambiar los datos de la página actual, etc, todo eso sin tener que refrescar la página. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6fju-td04) (**`Run - F9`** para probar). Así como ese botón que busca datos en el servidor y los trae a la página, puedes tener muchos otros para otras acciones.

Answer (score 1):

Funcionando

Me equivoque en esta parte del código:

```
     sub_array[] = '<a href="edit.php?id='.$idviaje.'" default">Editar</a>';
     $sub_array[] = '<a href="delete.php?id='.$idviaje.'" ">Eliminar</a>';
```

Este es el correcto:

```
     sub_array[] = '<a href="edit.php?idviaje='.$idviaje.'" default">Editar</a>';
     $sub_array[] = '<a href="delete.php?idviaje='.$idviaje.'" ">Eliminar</a>';
```